# IP address issue when deployed in Server

Tags: servlets, networking, cloud

I have a Servlet project developed using **Tomcat 7**.

My projects logic is that whenever a request comes from certain IP it responds to the same IP with a new instance of browser as an response.

When I run and test this application locally it works perfect and by the way my local working IP address will be something like this `10.52.xxx.xxx`. So request has `10.52.xxx.xxx` and response is given to `10.52.xxx.xxx` and all happies

Now things looks perfect and I planned to deploy this project in a Server which has an IP addess of `172.32.xxx.xxx` and I have completed deployment of the same.

Now the issue which I am facing is that when I try to make a request to the project in the server `(172.32.xxx.xxx)` from my network `(10.52.xxx.xxx)`.

In my project I have code like

```
String ip = request.getRemoteAddr(); //gets request IP address to give a new instance of browser
```

Now the variable **ip** contains an IP address of `172.32.xxx.xxx`. So my code will try to give a browser instance to `172.32.xxx.xxx` which doesn't exist. It should ideally give the browser instance back to `10.52.xxx.xxx` as this is from which it had received the request so it has to respond to this IP.

I know both Server and the client request are in different IP network but I would like to know all possible solutions to fix the same so that browser is given back to `10.52.xxx.xxx`.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: place the client ip address in a request attribute and use that value instead of getRemoteAddr

Comment: @awadheshv that will allow user to spoof the ip address

Comment: I don't want to make use of external server to get IP. even if I use I get some other IP than what I am looking for example in my cmd I see 10.52.xxx.xxx and using external services I get 152.35.xxx.xxx

Which I am not expecting it

@BalusC

Comment: @BalusC I have checked the duplicate post and I don't see the client IP (10.52.xxx.xxx) available in the request header. I see an IP of "43.254.163.221"
I tried with the following commands
String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");  // output = "43.254.163.221"
ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");  // output = null
ip = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP"); // output = null
 ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_CLIENT_IP"); // output = null
ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"); // output = null
 ip = request.getRemoteAddr();  //output = 10.117.18.18

but not 10.52.xxx.xxx